# Postgres Compare string to number return correct result

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to understand how postgres compare string to number because following queries return true,

```
SELECT 1 WHERE '1' = 1
SELECT 1 WHERE '1' <= 10
SELECT 1 WHERE '1' BETWEEN 1 and 10
SELECT 1 WHERE 1 BETWEEN '1' and '10'
```

Can someone please explain?

Comment: My advice is: Don't do this. Either deal with strings or with numbers. Don't mix the two. Don't use a varchar column for storing numbers either, but use a numeric datatype. If you are forced to deal with such a table, then either treat the column as a string in your queries or use some function / expression to ensure the content is numeric and cast / convert.

Comment: I think you are right, treating numbers is not correct, as per your answer `'12' BETWEEN '1' and '2' ` will return true as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL applies implicit conversion where necessary and possible. How it does this is no further explained as far as I know. (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/typeconv.html)

Anyway, we can play a little with your queries and find out what's happening:

```
SELECT '12' BETWEEN 1 and 2
```

would result in true for `SELECT '12' BETWEEN '1' and '2'` and false for `SELECT 12 BETWEEN 1 and 2`. Run it. It returns false.

Here is a further test:

```
SELECT 1 BETWEEN 'A' and '10'
```

This fails with `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "A"`.

So, PostgreSQL tries to convert the strings to numbers, because it thinks you want to deal with numbers here.

Comment: I want to throw in that Postgres's behavior is SQL standard -- as far as I know -- and this is how all databases behave (or at least should behave).